# Opening of first option navigation bar as soon as application starts java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oncreate, android-bottomnav

I am making an android project and i am a using bottom navigation bar with activities.While I click on the navigation bar buttons it works perfectly fine but when i start the application it shows me just a navigation bar .I want the first navigation bar option should show up as soon as I start the application but it is not happening .Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fragments to instantiate in the bottom navigation bar, you just need to instantiate the fragment in the onCreate Method and use the bottom navigation bar listener to use it to handle click listeners.

In this demo, I have a navigation bar which is being initialized using the listeners and after that, in the onCreate I instantiate the fragment to display when the fragment when created.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {@Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home_nav:
                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

                break;
            case R.id.explore_nav:
                selectedFragment = new ExploreFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
```

Comment: no sir am using activities in this case but i really appreciate your work .If you can help me with that i'll be really grateful to you.

Comment: I think it gets complicated to use bottom navigation bar without the fragments. but since u said the other buttons and activities are woking  then please show me the code and i will try helping you out